# How to access/save last deploy date for python app engine app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-deployment

How to store a date programatically whenever the app was last deployed? Do you set up a script which runs when you update the app or is this information stored in some meta property in the app engine sdk?

Comment: Most of the information is stored in the app engine console, under `Versions`. Are you asking how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Yes my question has the word programmatically in it yes ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Not sure if this will be helpful, but the current version is available in the environment: `os.getenv('CURRENT_VERSION_ID')`.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to do this as some sort of security or team management effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that there is any means to programatically access the last deployment data, not without some level of intervention.

- It is possible to [obtain information about the environment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Environment), which contains the running application version.
- It is also possible to [download a previous version](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code).

My suggestion, given this information, would be to do the following:

1. Ensure that a file with the necessary metadata is included when the app is deployed
2. Fetch the latest version of the app
3. Parse the metadata file

Unfortunately, this means downloading the entire app, but it seems like there is no other documentation on this matter. Although, knowing why you need this information could make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Its just for showing for logged in users in the CMS, so they can se when the app was last deployed.